# updating an assembly in a live ASP.NET web application without displaying temporaries runtime errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

does someone know how to update an assembly on a live ASP.NET web application in a way that the application stops displaying a runtime error page while the assembly is being copied into the bin folder ?

Context:
ASP.NET 4
IIS 7.5
ASP.NET Web application with a /bin folder

I'm using SFTP to copy one of the new assembly into the bin folder. It takes about 20 seconds to complete.
I suspect iis detect a change in the bin folder and recycles the application before the assembly is completely copied.

When the assembly is fully copied the application works correctly again.

Do you know a good configuration which would prevent this problem ?

EDIT--------------

This asp.net application is bind to 2 different domain names, say a.app.com and b.appa.com
The domain name is used to select a theme before each page is displayed.

Using App_Offline.htm won't work in this case or you need to create an unbranded page.

EDIT 2--------------

App_Offline.htm also won't work with ajax requests, JSON or not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx

Create this page and use it you need to upload the dlls. After the dll is uploaded rename it to something else.

Comment: well, nice idea. This may work in a normal asp.net website, but won't in mine. I added some explainations why.